# regular expression c# password remove spaces

Tags: c#, regex

Im have a nice regular expression builder that looks like this:

```
string numberOfDigits = "2";
string numberOfCaps = "2";
string numberOfChars = "3";
string numberOfNonAlpha = "3";
string minLength = "10";

string rexExString = "^(?=.*\\d{" + numberOfDigits + "})(?=.*[A-Z]{" + numberOfCaps + "})(?=.*[a-z]{" + numberOfChars + "})(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]{" + numberOfNonAlpha + "}).{" + minLength + ",}$";
```

output will then be:

```
^(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[A-Z]{2})(?=.*[a-z]{3})(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]{3}).{10,}$
```

This way I can specify how many digits, chars, nonalpha etc i want for my password. I want to keep it this way. The only problem is it also accept spaces, and i dont want that for my passwords.

My question

**How to not allow spaces in my regex, but keep it in the format so i can specify the variables as in the example above.**

```
^(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[A-Z]{2})(?=.*[a-z]{3})(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]{3}).{10,}$
```

Comment: Your regex forces 2 digits to occur *together*, similarly for the other checks - is that really what you want? Most password policies just insist on the number of characters, not where they occur.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\d`. You should use `[0-9]`. `\d` matches non-european digits http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1c0s6bb.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are not the spaces in your format the problem is that you allow ALL characters with your `.{10,}` at the end.

Try this instead

```
\S{10,}
```

`\S` is not a whitespace (same as `[^\s]`)

Btw. are you aware that you want to have 2 digits in a sequence with `(?=.*\d{2})` and not two digits overall? That means Foo1bar2 would not be accepted.

**What about simplifying this?**

Putting all your requirements into one regular expression is a bit hard. Especially if you want to allow a configurable amount of digits to be distributed among the password and not in a sequence.

Why not split this verification process a bit.

You can as first step just check for `^\S{10,}$` to ensure that there are at least 10 non whitespace characters in the password.

Then you could count the types of characters, e.g. like this:

```
MatchCollection uppercase = Regex.Matches(s, @"\p{Lu}");
MatchCollection lowercase = Regex.Matches(s, @"\p{Ll}");
MatchCollection digits = Regex.Matches(s, @"\p{N}");
MatchCollection nonAlpha = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\p{N}\p{L}]");

Console.WriteLine("Upper: " + uppercase.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Lower: " + lowercase.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Digits: " + digits.Count);
Console.WriteLine("NonAlpha: " + nonAlpha.Count);
```

Just match one character of the class you want and then get the amount of those characters using the `count()` method of the `MatchCollection`.

I used the Unicode properties here (the `\p{...}`), you can change that easily to the character classes you want. Here is an [overview over the Unicode properties on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

You can then get the amount of each character type and compare it to the number you require of that specific type.

This would be a much more readable and maintainable function.

Comment: thanks, i really copy and pasted the whole thing together, your way of dealing with it is ideal for my sitiuation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.{10,}$` in the end you could specify that there should be atleast 10 non-space characters `\S{10,}$`.

```
\S{" + minLength + ",}$
```

Note the uppercase S.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^((?<N>[0-9])|(?<CU>[A-Z])|(?<CL>[a-z])|(?<NA>[!@#$%&*()^])| )*$(?<-N>){3}(?<-CU>){1}(?<-CL>){2}(?<-NA>){4}");
```

This regex uses balancing groups to "accumulate" the various types of characters. It will reject characters not in (those groups plus space). So for example `è` would be rejected. If you want to change it, replace the `| )` with `|.)`

At the end of the string (`$`) it checks if there are enough characters in all the various "stacks". Clearly where you see `{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}` you'll have to put your numbers.

Note that the interesting thing of this Regex is that it will work for `1!A!a!2!b3`. If you want the various classes of characters to be contiguous (so `123Abc!!!!`) then this Regex isn't "good".